# Application of Variational Forms of PDE's

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

This is more of a question of why I **cannot** do the following.

Suppose we have the two PDE's,
\begin{align}
Lu&=f,\\
Pu&=f.
\end{align}

Let $a_{L}(u,v)=(f,v)$ and $a_{P}(u,v)=(f,v)$ be the variational forms associated to the PDE with operator $L$ and $P$, respectively. Clearly, $a_{L}(u,v)\neq a_{P}(u,v)$ but what is the reason I cannot write the following,
\begin{align}
a_{L}(u,v)=(f,v)=a_{P}(u,v)?
\end{align}
I know that this isn't true, but I cannot identify the reasoning which says the statement above cannot be written down.

---

I recently showed that the bilinear form associated to,
\begin{align}
Lu+\mu u+\lambda m u=f\geq 0,
\end{align}
is coercive ($\lambda,\mu>0$, $f\in L^{2}(\Omega)$, $m\in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ with $m\geq 0$ and $m(x)>0$ for some $x\in\Omega$), with $Lu:=-\text{div}(A\nabla u+\textbf{a}u)+(\textbf{b}\cdot\nabla u+cu)$. This coercivity actually is independent of the $\lambda m u$ term, that is what is really shown is,
\begin{align}
a(v,v)+\mu(v,v)+\lambda(mv,v)\geq a(v,v)+\mu(v,v)\geq\alpha\|v\|_{H^{1}}^{2}\quad\forall v\in H^{1}(\Omega).
\end{align}
So this inherently means that the bilinear form associated with the problem,
\begin{align}
Lu+\mu u=f\geq 0,
\end{align}
is coercive. I wish to use this coercivity to now show that $u\to 0$ in $L^{2}(\Omega_{\delta})$ where $\Omega_{\delta}:=\{x\in\Omega\,|\,m(x)\geq\delta>0\}$.

My idea is to use the fact that,
\begin{align}
\alpha\|v\|_{H^{1}}^{2}&\leq a(v,v)+\mu(v,v)\\
\implies\alpha\|v\|_{H^{1}}^{2}+\lambda(mv,v)&\leq a(v,v)+\mu(v,v)+\lambda(mv,v)=(f,v)\leq\|f\|_{2}\|v\|_{2}.
\end{align}
However, I don't know if I am using the equality with $(f,v)$ correctly, since  both $Lu+\mu u=f$ and $Lu+\mu u+\lambda mu=f$.

Comment: Are the spaces for $u$ and $v$ identical?

Comment: Yes they both belong to $H^{1}(\Omega)$.

Comment: If $Lu = f$ and $Pu = f$, you get $Lu = Pu$ or $(L-P)u = 0$ and you recover $a_L(u,v) = a_P(u,v)$. But, indeed, $a_L(w,z)$ is different from $a_P(w,z)$. The equality is only valid for the specific function $u$.

Comment: Hmmmm, allow me to edit my post and give some context to where the question came from.

Comment: Am I interpreting $u$ incorrectly? I am seeing it as the same $u$ is a solution to both PDE's. Should I really be considering $u_{1}$ and $u_{2}$ that are not identical and solutions for their respective PDE's? And in this case $a(u_{1},v)+\mu(u_{1},v)=a(u_{2},v)+\mu(u_{2},v)+\lambda(mu_{2},v)$?

Comment: Right you have two different solutions: $L u_L = f$ and $P u_P = f$.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help!